# tar archiving via cron does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, tar

I am trying to archive my localhost's root folder with tar and want to automate it's execution on a daily basis with crontab. For this purpose, I created a 'backupfolder' in my personal folder. I am running on Ubuntu 12.04.

The execution of tar in the command line works fine without problems:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf backupfolder/localhost.tar.gz /var/www
```

However, when I schedule the command for a daily backup (let's say at 17.00) in `sudo crontab -e`, it is not executing, i.e. the backup does not update using the following command:

```
0 17 * * * sudo tar -cpzf backupfolder/localhost.tar.gz /var/www
```

I already tried the full path `home/user/backupfolder/localhost.tar.gz` without success.

`var/log/syslog` gives me the following output for the scheduled execution:

```
Feb  2 17:00:01 DESKTOP-PC CRON[12052]: (root) CMD (sudo tar -cpzfbackupfolder/localhost.tar.gz /var/www)
Feb  2 17:00:01 DESKTOP-PC CRON[12051]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

`/etc/crontab` specifies the following path:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I assume that crontab is not executing as this is a sudo command.

Is there a way how I can get this running? What is the recommended, safe way if I don't want to hardcode my root password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the command that works for you is

```
sudo tar -cvpzf backupfolder/localhost.tar.gz /var/www
```

Which means, you have to run the command with sudo access, and it will not work from within your crontab.

I would suggest adding the cron job to the root user's crontab.

Basically, do

`sudo crontab -e`

And add an entry there

```
0 17 * * * cd /home/user/backupfolder && tar -cpzf localhost.tar.gz /var/www
```

If that doesn't work, add the full path of tar (like `/bin/tar`).

Also, while debugging, set the cronjob to run every minute (`* * * * *`)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is the sudo command so we will allow sudo to run tar for the "user" without prompting for the password.

Add the following line in `/etc/sudoers` file.

***user*** ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/tar

where ***user*** is the user installing the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a PATH problem, try to set some variables at the top of `sudo crontab -e` :

```
MAILTO=your_email@domain.tld # to get the output if there's errors
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: I added the suggested path, but unfortunatley it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your command in a script like run.sh

```
#/bin/sh -l
tar -cvpzf backupfolder/localhost.tar.gz /var/www
```

then use the crontab to run the script.

IMPORTANT NOTE: the script's first line has the "-l" option. 
Try it.